# Python - How to Download Images from Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, boto3

I need to download images that are uploaded by https://webapp.spypoint.com. These images are saved in Amazon S3. The url for this image is something like this as: https://s3.amazonaws.com/spypoint/1111/2222/3333/img.jpg

I have id and password to log in https://webapp.spypoint.com. My goal is to download images from Amazon S3 directly using boto3.

I researched about it and all information was about downloading images from Amazon S3 bucket owned by myself. For my case, the Amazon S3 storage/bucket is owned by https://webapp.spypoint.com.

Comment: Are you saying that the images are stored in an Amazon S3 bucket that is owned by somebody else's AWS account? If you know the names of the files, and if they are publicly accessible, then you can download then. Otherwise, they will not be accessible. You will need to ask the bucket owner to make them accessible to your AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

Without any knowledge on how the image is served on the website you meintioned It would be hard to answer.

However, generally I belive that:

1/ The bucket do not enable public object listing

2/ The bucket do not enable public object getting

3/ The images you see is displayed on your screen with a signed url ( check your network in the browser console )

If that is the case, you will only be able to get directly get the S3 URLs ( the download links ) that is explicitly provided (to you ) by the website you are targeting.

You need to look into APIs that website provide or do HTML parsing